# How much reputation is needed to cast a vote in an election?

Tags: support, election

I noticed that MO is currently holding moderator elections, and I'm curious whether or not I will be able to vote. I've looked through the privileges list, and I do not see mentioned there a "participate in an election" privilege of any sort. How much reputation is needed to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sidebar on the election page gives the answer:

> In the election phase, up to 10 candidates advance to final community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   election.

Comment: I caught that part, but I was wondering how much reputation is needed to vote in an election, not to self-nominate.

Comment: @CameronBuie I've corrected that, it's written in the sidebar but on the election page, and not the nomination page, I got a bit confused between those two.

Comment: Aha! My thanks!

Comment: Of course, it *means* any member with *at least* 150 reputation.  I hope.